# Inverse of $(A + B)$ and $(A + BCD)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider $A$ as an arbitrary matrix and $B$ as a symmetric matrix. Since $B$ is symmetric, therefore, it can be written as a $\Gamma \Delta \Gamma'$, where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix with eigen-values on the the main diagonal and $\Gamma$ is a matrix of corresponding eigenvectors.

Is there any formula for $(A + B)^{-1}$?

Now, consider $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ as arbitrary matrices. Is there any formula for:
$(A + BCD)^{-1}$

Application: I'm fitting a model that involves matrix inversion. My matrix can be decomposed into two parts. At each step, only one part of the matrix gets updated, if I can find a formula for the inverse of the matrices above, then I don't need to invert the whole matrix and instead, I can only invert the part that has been updated.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: For an arbitrary matrix $A$, $(A+B)$ is in general not invertible. Even if you take $A$ to be invertible then also its not true. To write down a formula you have to check first whether they are invertible or not. Essentially you need a formula for $det(A+B).$ I know one formula but that's not very impressive. Here is the link http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=262036&userType=inst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the woodbury matrix inversion AKA Matrix Inversion Lemma?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: That's nice. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your welcome. I hope it was what you were looking for :)

Comment: I appreciate that. Very helpful :)